# is componentDidMount rerender the component?

Tags: reactjs

> At first my favorite color is red, but give me a second, and it is yellow instead.
> will componentDidMount cause the component rerender to display color yellow?

```
    class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {favoritecolor: "red"};
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({favoritecolor: "yellow"})
    }, 1000)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>My Favorite Color is {this.state.favoritecolor}</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: `componentDidMount` renders once after the first render. So yes, it will re-render to show yellow and the timeout doesn't change that

Comment: @GregM I used counter instead of fav color, it is updating the state(increasing the counter on every second. I can not undertand the difference between componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.

Comment: `componentDidMount()` renders 1 time after the first render. `componentDidUpdate` will be called after each state update. So after each `setState`. Using `setState` inside `componentDidUpdate()` will cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the React docs:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree).

so yes, but...

Also from the docs:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state.

That means you will only see the yellow color.

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` is a lifecycle method that is called only when the component is mounted. It is called only once after the first render.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Runs after the first render() lifecycle
}
```

When React looks at this code, it’s going to first render the component (the `constructor()` is the first method called) and you will see at first the color is `red`.

Right after that, React checks if the component has `componentDidMount()` method to run any side effects.

In your `componentDidMount()` method, you're telling React to update the state of the component.

So that, `this.state.favoritecolor` went from `red` to `yellow`.

**Helpful Link**: [Understanding React componentDidMount and how it works](https://linguinecode.com/post/understanding-react-componentdidmount)

Comment: If it is updating the state whenever we tell to react to update the state, really i can not understand the difference between componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.

Comment: `componentDidMount` is called at the beginning, and the `componentDidUpdate` is called upon every update. They are not interchangeable. [React Lifecycle Methods Diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).